# WPF в С# проблема с custom

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть код XAML и есть класс `CustomVisualFrameworkElement`, который унаследован от `FrameworkElement` и реализует с помощью `Visual` некоторые фигуры. Но XAML почему то не видит данный класс, хотя я подключаю пространство, которое содержит класс `CustomVisualFrameworkElement`

КОД XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="RenderingWithVisuals.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:RenderingWithVisuals" //Вот тут я подключаю пространство в котором находится класс CustomVisualFrameworkElement       
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <StackPanel Name="MyStackPAnel">
        <Image Height="80" Name="MyImage" />
        <!--Теперь используем наш класс, который содержит в себе фигуры и инфраструктуру от FrameworkElement-->
        <custom: CustomVisualFrameworkElement/> //Вот тут не видит класс
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нет. unknown команда...

Comment: @FoggyFinder, обновил вопрос

Comment: @batya: У вас там объявлено `xmlns:local`, а по факту используется `custom:CustomVisualFrameworkElement`.

Comment: @FoggyFinder, я же говорил, что с loacl та же самая проблема. Пруф в  вопросе.

Comment: @batya: А если сделать так: (1) Убрать из XAML `<local:CustomVisualFrameworkElement/>`, (2) Перекомпилировать проект и убедиться, что он компилируется без ошибок, (3) Добавить `<local:CustomVisualFrameworkElement/>` назад?

Comment: @VladD, Спасибо. Помогло. Можете сделать свой комментарий ответом? А я поставлю галочку.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если с кодом всё в порядке, помогает следующий алгоритм:

1. Убрать из XAML `<local:CustomVisualFrameworkElement/>`,
2. Перекомпилировать проект и убедиться, что он компилируется без ошибок,
3. Добавить `<local:CustomVisualFrameworkElement/>` назад.

Разоблачение магии: WPF компилирует проект в два прохода: сначала XAML (при этом генерируется код на C#), потом весь code-behind. Если у вас есть свежий класс в code-behind, который упомянут в XAML'е, то при компиляции XAML'а его ещё не видно, и первый этап компиляции проваливается. Убирая новый элемент, мы даём первому этапу компиляции завершиться, и компилятор наконец-то видит новый класс.

Да, это баг в Visual Studio.

Comment: Можно переключить debug/release и скомпилировать, потом переключить назад. Так тоже работает.

Comment: @Андрей: Круто, не знал. Если проект небольшой, это может быть и быстрее, кстати.