# WPF не видит kласс в пространстве имен

Tags: c#, wpf

Ситуация такая : В проекте создал папку `Converters` и в нее добавил новый класс
`TagToImageSourceConverter`. В Заголовке разметки добавил ссылку на эту папку вот так :

> xmlns:imgC="clr-namespace:Custodian.DALs.InterfaceService.Converters"

Далее я пытаюсь обратиться к классу в папке вот так :

```
<Image.Resources>
<imgC:TagToImageSourceConverter x:Key="TagImgConverter"/>
</Image.Resources>
```

На что студия выдает ошибку - в данном пространстве имен не содержится `TagToImageSourceConverter`. Раньше такие ошибки появлялись и скоро исчезали так же загадочно и быстро. На этот раз хочу разобраться в чем проблема.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот это не подходит? https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618503/10105

Comment: @VladD если все лишнее убрать-скомпилить и снова добавлять то даже папку `Converters` не видит и ошибку выдает уже в заголовке на `xmlns:name="....Converters"`

Comment: А какую конкретно ошибку? И да, а в каком namespace находится `TagToImageSourceConverter`? (Каталог не имеет значения, только namespace.) Перепроверьте.

Comment: @VladD namespace был неверен. спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Хорошо, что разобрались.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это вроде ошибка не разметки, а видимости классов в C# -- у тебя наверное и внутри проекта этот класс не видно, экземпляр не создать, да?
попробуй открыть TagToImagesourceconverter.CS и "обернуть" класс в namespace решения/проекта; т.е. типа:

```
namespace Custodian //предположительное пространство имён решения/проекта
{
  class TagToImagesourceconverter
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: дело действительно было в наймспейсах. спасибо за подсказку!