# Ошибка XDG0008 Имя "MainVM" не существует в пространстве имен "clr-namespace:StepByStepServer.ViewModels"

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Не могу понять в чем проблема. MainVM существует в StepByStepServer.ViewModels. Мне даже ItelliSens его подсказывает в качестве DataContext, когда вписываю его в Xaml. Приложение нормально собирается и при сборке подтягивает MainVM. 
Но в редакторе ругается и не компилирует xaml-разметку.

У меня регулярно возникает такая ошибка и всякий раз решается путем странных манипуляций с файлами, неймспейсами и кодом. И в какой-то момент View все-таки находит VM. 
Не могу понять, как решать эту ошибку?

[image: Скриншот View]
[image: Скриншот VM]
[image: Скриншот DataContex]

Заметил в выводе вот такое. Может из-за этого проблема?

C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_038c39d7\Designer\ShadowCache\sthjutrr.znm\1sb2wpcf.lni\Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.dll
    Предпринята попытка загрузить сборку из сетевого ресурса, что в предыдущих версиях .NET Framework могло привести к помещению сборки в "песочницу". Этот выпуск .NET Framework не включает политику CAS по умолчанию, поэтому данная загрузка может быть опасной. Если эта нагрузка не предназначена для изоляции сборки, включите переключатель loadFromRemoteSources. Дополнительные сведения см. на странице http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=155569.

ShadowCache чистить пробовал.

Comment: Переключение с debug на release и обратно не помогает. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14665713/the-name-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-error-in-xaml

Comment: Убрать, скомпилировать, добавить: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/618507/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP, это первое что я пробовал. К сожалению, не помогает.

Comment: Да, как оказалось проблема была в заблокированных DLL. 
Потребовалось разблокировать их. После очистить кэш. И наконец-то View увидела VM!

Comment: @АлександрЛи ответьте тогда сами на свой вопрос ответом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема была в заблокиррванных dll(после скачивания исходников). Нужно открыть исходники в проводнике. И в свойства dll файлов нажать "Разблокировать".
После нужно почистить ShadowCache(гуглится). И скомпилировать проект.