# Визаулка выдала ошибку там,где её нет wpf c# Window.DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ошибка вылетела сама по себе,не могу работать из-за неё,раньше было но помогло пересборка решения но сейчас не помогло,прошу помочь

Comment: Класс сделайте публичным, из XAML удалите эти строки, пересоберите проект, верните строки. Если не помогло, закройте студию, удалите `obj` и `bin` и проделайте все повторно. Если и это не помогло, то значит у вас не совпадают `namespace`. Ну а вообще, оставлю [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553) здесь.

Comment: помогло слова богу,но печально что присутствуют такие баги в проге

Comment: Наверное, не дубликат, но очень похожая проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618503/10105

Comment: @VladD проблема схожая, а причина одна и та же, и ответ прямо в тему. Закрываю.

Comment: Вообще вьюмодель лучше не в XAML подключать, а в App.xaml.cs/OnStartup() - читайте про точку сборки (composition root) - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/373567. И еще ссылка, где я показываю, как собрать в одно целое вьюмодели и вью в OnStartup() - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1266479/373567

Comment: @aepot Забавно, помниться кто-то меня ругал за то, что я всем давал совет на подключение VM в App, мол на "большом SO" заминусовали дяди за такой подход. Что же теперь изменилось, дяди похвалили?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ я научился с тех пор писать код для больше, чем одного окна. Ну и IoC освоил, что как бы автоматом исключает вариант с прямым вкручиванием экземпляра вьюмодели в окно. Но вкручивание в разметку вьюмодели дает свои преимущества - легкая отладка в дизайнере сразу с подсказками IntelliSense, что для новичка вполне себе неплохо.

Comment: @aepot Да, только это несовместимо с MVVM, ибо как минимум окно не должно управлять VM. А IntelliSense `d:DataContext = ...`. Ну а так рад, что вы поняли все это.